# how set two DAGs in airflow using ExternalTaskSensor?

Tags: triggers, dependencies, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have two DAG's:

**DAG_CPS**

```
dag = DAG(
  'DAG_CPS',
  default_args=default_args,
  dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
  schedule_interval=None,
  max_active_runs=1
) 
tmp1_cap_pes_sap = PostgresOperatorWithTemplatedParams(
task_id='tmp1_cap_pes_sap',
sql='./SQL/A2050.sql',
postgres_conn_id='xxxx',
dag=dag) 
...
```

**DAG_SAS**

```
dag = DAG(
'DAG_SAS',
default_args=default_args,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
schedule_interval=None,
max_active_runs=1
)

wait_for_DAG_CPS = ExternalTaskSensor(
task_id='wait_for_DAG_CPS',
external_dag_id='DAG_CPS',
external_task_id='tmp1_cap_pes_sap',
execution_delta=None,
execution_date_fn=None,
dag=dag)
```

I trigger both DAGs manually from the web, the task tmp1_cap_pes_sap ends ok

```
Attribute       Value
dag_id          DAG_CPS
duration        None
end_date        2018-08-24 11:04:28.177221
execution_date  2018-08-24 11:04:18.113031
```

but in DAG_SAS I obtain the next log and it never start

```
[2018-08-24 11:03:55,592] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-24 11:03:55,592] {sensors.py:243} INFO - Poking for DAG_CPS.tmp1_cap_pes_sap on 2018-08-24T11:03:50.518595 ... 
[2018-08-24 11:04:55,642] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-24 11:04:55,641] {sensors.py:243} INFO - Poking for DAG_CPS.tmp1_cap_pes_sap on 2018-08-24T11:03:50.518595 ... 
[2018-08-24 11:05:55,718] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-24 11:05:55,717] {sensors.py:243} INFO - Poking for DAG_CPS.tmp1_cap_pes_sap on 2018-08-24T11:03:50.518595 ... 
[2018-08-24 11:06:55,799] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-24 11:06:55,797] {sensors.py:243} INFO - Poking for DAG_CPS.tmp1_cap_pes_sap on 2018-08-24T11:03:50.518595 ... 
[2018-08-24 11:07:55,853] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-24 11:07:55,853] {sensors.py:243} INFO - Poking for DAG_CPS.tmp1_cap_pes_sap on 2018-08-24T11:03:50.518595 ...
```

what is wrong in my code?

***Solved***

thanks to @Alessandro Cosentino for help me. This is the code after fixing it, basically it will never work if I launch the DAG manually

**DAG_CPS**

```
default_args = {
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
'retries': 2,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG(
'DAG_CPS',
default_args=default_args,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=5),
schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
max_active_runs=1
)
```

**DAG_SAS**

```
dag = DAG(
'DAG_SAS',
default_args=default_args,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=5),
schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
max_active_runs=1
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're triggering the tasks manually, they will be running with different `execution_date`, which is the reason why the ExternalTaskSensor doesn't detect completion of the first DAG's task.

Try to run them on the same schedule instead and see if it works.

I assume that's the problem, because of the existence of the `execution_delta` and `execution_date_fn` arguments, which are there in fact to synchronized the two DAGs. See [the docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.html) for the behaviour of those two arguments.

Comment: thank's @Alessandro Cosentino, it works, these is my new code

DAG_CPS

default_args = {
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 2,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG(
'DAG_CPS',
default_args=default_args,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=5),
schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
max_active_runs=1
)
DAG_SAS

dag = DAG(
'DAG_SAS',
default_args=default_args,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=5),
schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
max_active_runs=1
)

Comment: @cimujo Cool, remember to accept the answer if you are satisfied with the solution.

Comment: @cimujo Also, it's nicer if instead of commenting here, you edit the question by adding a section with the new code, so that it gets formatted properly ;-)